# getting values from the adapter onListItemClick

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

From my main activity I am inserting string into database and by using cursor adding few values in array adapter,My main class is:

```
 public class main{
        message = datasource.createMessage(messages,ch,random);
         ArrayAdapter<Message> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Message>) getListAdapter();
             adapter.add(message);
            public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
                      super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

                      Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                              "position: "+position+" "+"Id: "+id+getListAdapter().getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            

                  String str=getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

              }
}
```

When I get all the my messages in list I have three values in adapter id, message and threadid and I want to get the value of threadid onListItemClick..How to get the values using adapter in onListItemClick method??Please help and my datasource class where I query database and get object using cursor and add in to adapter..

```
 public class datasource{
      private String[] allColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MESSAGE,MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID };

                public Message createMessage(String message,char ch,int random) {
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                if(ch=='s')
                values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_STATUS, "s");
            if(ch=='r')
                values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_STATUS, "r");

                values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PARENTID, 0);

                values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID, random);

            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MESSAGE, message);
            long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null,
                values);


           Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME,
                allColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
           /* Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME,
                    allColumns, null, null,
                    null, null, null);*/
           cursor.moveToFirst();
            Message newMessage = cursorToMessage(cursor);
           cursor.close();
            return newMessage;
          }
         private Message cursorToMessage(Cursor cursor) {
            Message message = new Message();
            message.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
           // message.setparentid(cursor.getLong(1));
            message.setmessage(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("message")));
            message.setthreadid(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("threadid")));
         //  message.status(cursor.getString(4)); 
            return message;

          }
}
```

Comment: whats happening now? are you not getting position values??

Comment: yeah am getting position and id but I also want to get one more thing "threadid" which i have added in the adapter...